# How do I insert if statement inside numpy.where()?

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
compare_values =data1.values == data2.values
rows, columns = numpy.where(compare_values == False)
```

and get validator check:

```
E712 comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:'
```

`data1` and `data2` are of type data frame

`rows` and `columns` are arrays.

I tried inserting if statement inside `numpy.where()` but that does not work.

```
compare_values =data1.values == data2.values
rows, columns = numpy.where(compare_values == False)
```

I am getting the following validation check:

```
E712 comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:'
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe your validator wants `numpy.where(~compare_values)`? Or just create `compare_values` using `!=` instead of `==` in the first place.

Comment: yes I am looking for elementwise negation to check for True and False. My code is running fime but I get validatior error. @Dan

Comment: Probably not a solution to this but in this case I would rather use [numpy.nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) instead of numpy.where

Comment: @SiddheshShankar ok... but does `numpy.where(~compare_values)` still give you a validator error?

Comment: You could also just pass compare_values instead of the condition and it should work

Comment: @RickM. If I just pass compare_values inside the brackets, that does not work

Comment: On using the following code :rows, columns = numpy.where(compare_values is False)
I get this error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: That `E712` is a check against `pep8`, not a Python/numpy error.  That's a valid style issue for pure Python, but not for `numpy`.  `np.array([False, True,False])==False` perfectly good `numpy`, just as good as the `~`.  I've added a better duplicate.

Comment: Keep in mind that the argument to `np.where` (alias `np.nonzero`) is evaluated before being passed to the function.  So `compare_values == False` or `~compare_values` has to generate a valid `numpy` boolean array.  `data1.values != data2.values` is another way.  `np.nonzero` just gives us the indices of the `True` (nonzero) values.